# relativedelta使用時のilocについて

Tags: python, python3, pandas

`iloc`について教えてください。

`for i in range(len(predict_data)):` とした場合、`i` に入るのは整数なので、`.iloc[i]` とすべきだと思ったのですが、解答では `iloc` を使わず、下記のようになっておりました。
なぜ、`iloc` 省略なのでしょうか。
できれば初学者用に分かりやすく教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
for i in range(len(predict_data)):
　　    delta = relativedelta(predict_data["now_date"][i], predict_data["start_date"][i])
```

Comment: こんなにご丁寧に教えてくださり、本当にありがとうございます！分かったつもりでもすぐこんがらがってしまいますので、今後、何度も読み返させていただきます。本当にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

質問のやり方は行番号では無く「インデックス値」によるアクセスです。
インデックス値が`0からの連番`で付加されているため、行番号で行を指定したのと同等の処理になった訳です。

pandasのドキュメントでは以下に記述されています。
[Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

> **Note**
> The Python and NumPy indexing operators`[]`and attribute operator`.`provide quick and easy access to pandas data structures across a wide range of use cases.

[Basics](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#basics)

> the primary function of indexing with`[]`(a.k.a.`__getitem__`for those familiar with implementing class behavior in Python) is selecting out lower-dimensional slices.
>
> | **Object Type** | **Selection** | **Return Value Type** |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Series | `series[label]` | scalar value |
> | DataFrame | `frame[colname]` | `Series` corresponding to colname |

こんな日本語の解説記事もあります。
[インデックスに基づく選択 - pandas – Series のインデックス操作まとめ](https://pystyle.info/pandas-indexing-series/#outline__4_1)

---

質問の出展はこちらだと思われますが
[Python実践データ分析100本ノック （単行本）](https://www.shuwasystem.co.jp/book/9784798058757.html)

> 第4章 顧客の行動を予測する10本　ノック
> ノック37：特徴となる変数を付与しよう
> [サンプルファイルのダウンロード - Python実践データ分析100本ノック](https://www.shuwasystem.co.jp/support/7980html/5875.html)

他に多数の人が記事を書いていて例えばこんな解説があります
[【Python実践データ分析100本ノック】ノック36－40](https://minarai-engi.com/python-analytics100knock-8/)

質問の行近辺の`predict_data.head()`の結果や、直前の`predict_data["period"]=None`が実行された時点で単に`predict_data["now_date"]`とか`predict_data["start_date"]`として内容を表示してみれば分かりますが、各データには`0`～`15112`という`数値(整数)によるインデックス`が付いています。

```
>>> predict_data.head()
       年月 customer_id  count_pred  count_0  count_1  count_2  count_3  count_4  count_5
0  201810    AS002855           3      7.0      3.0      5.0      5.0      5.0      4.0
1  201810    AS009373           5      6.0      6.0      7.0      4.0      4.0      3.0
2  201810    AS015315           4      7.0      3.0      6.0      3.0      3.0      6.0
3  201810    AS015739           5      6.0      5.0      8.0      6.0      5.0      7.0
4  201810    AS019860           7      5.0      7.0      4.0      6.0      8.0      6.0
...
>>> predict_data['now_date']
0       2018-10-01
1       2018-10-01
2       2018-10-01
3       2018-10-01
4       2018-10-01
           ...
15108   2019-03-01
15109   2019-03-01
15110   2019-03-01
15111   2019-03-01
15112   2019-03-01
Name: now_date, Length: 15113, dtype: datetime64[ns]
...
>>> predict_data['start_date']
0       2016-11-01
1       2015-11-01
2       2015-07-01
3       2017-06-01
4       2017-10-01
           ...
15108   2015-09-01
15109   2018-09-01
15110   2016-06-01
15111   2017-03-01
15112   2017-04-01
Name: start_date, Length: 15113, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

なので、`predict_data["now_date"][i]`とか`predict_data["start_date"][i]`とすると、各Seriesデータ中の`iの数値をインデックス値に持つデータ`にアクセス出来ることになります。

Comment: こちらの状況、実力、混乱部分を的確に察してくださり、心から感謝申し上げます！また分かりやすく資料を添付してくださったので、この問題を深く理解することができました。本当にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

元データが `DataFrame` (2次元)だった場合, その中から一つの項目を取り出すには

- 行(ROW)・列(COLUMN) を同時に指定する
- あるいは 一つずつ指定することができる
  一つずつの場合にも どの軸を先に指定するかで(当然)指定方法が異なる

  - `df[COLUMN][ROW]`
  - `df.loc[ROW][COLUMN]`

`df[カラム名][n]` のような指定では, カラム名にて 1列分 `Series` を取り出しその中から `[n]`で項目を取り出す手順
(複数続けるので) chained indexing とも呼ばれる
`[n]` の指定は, `DataFrame`に対するものではなく **途中**結果の `Series` に対する指定
(なので `loc` / `iloc` は必要ない)

##### chained indexing

chained indexing は(理解して使う分にはよいが) 問題点もある

- 内部でコピーが発生する可能性がある (ので微妙に遅くなるかも知れない)
- 暗黙の型変換が発生する場合がある (誤差が生じる場合がある)
- 新しい値の代入時に 想定外の結果になる可能性がある

以下の例は, 複数(3種類)の型のデータが `df.iloc[1]` で `object` 型に纏められた様子
(コピーが発生したはずで, (型変換で)誤差も発生するかも知れない)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
csv = io.StringIO('''
idx,日付,整数値項目,少数点数項目
A,2022-10-1,100,3.2
B,2022-10-2,200,0.1
C,2022-10-3,100,
D,2022-10-4,100,1.2
''')
df = pd.read_csv(csv, index_col=0, parse_dates=[1])
print(df.dtypes)
# 日付        datetime64[ns]
# 整数値項目              int64
# 少数点数項目           float64
# dtype: object

df.iloc[1]
# 日付        2022-10-02 00:00:00
# 整数値項目                     200
# 少数点数項目                    0.1
# Name: B, dtype: object
```

… なので, `df.loc[ROW][COLUMN]` の chained indexing は(データにもよるが)**避けたほうがよい**
(`df['整数値項目']` のような指定であれば, `int64` のまま, 変換は行われない)

---

##### 行・列を同時に指定

ちなみに
2次元 (matrix あるいは DataFrame) から値を取り出す場合, 以下の方法があります
(どちらかの軸 片方が番号の場合, `.index`, `.columns` など利用して変換するとよいでしょう)

| ＼ | ラベルで指定 | 番号で位置指定 | 備考 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 単独(single value)および 複数の要素の値 | [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) | [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) | 行だけの指定の場合 行を取り出す |
| 単独(single value)の要素の値 | [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) | [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) |  |

Table: `DataFrame`の場合 (`Series`の同名メソッドは 別ページ)