# データフレームで１つの列の要素の一部に２をかけたい

Tags: python, pandas

以下のようなデータフレームあります
2列目の値を2倍にしたいですが、
インデックスと項目名はないので、
どのようなコードを書けば良いでしょうか？
ご教示いただけましたら幸いですので、どうぞよろしくお願いします！
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 行番号や列番号で指定する方法があります https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/91496/relativedelta使用時のilocについて/91525#91525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
2022/1/1 0:30,250
2022/1/1 1:00,220
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data), header=None)

#
print(df)
df.iloc[:,1] *= 2
print(df)

#                0    1
# 0  2022/1/1 0:30  250
# 1  2022/1/1 1:00  220
#
#                0    1
# 0  2022/1/1 0:30  500
# 1  2022/1/1 1:00  440
```

Answer (score 1):

列名を指定しない場合、0から始まる連番の列名が自動的に生成されますので、列名に`1`を指定することで2列目の値を書き換えることができます。

**サンプルコード**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
s = """ 
2022/01/01 0:30:00,250
2022/01/01 1:00:00,200
""" 
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=None)
df[1] = df[1] * 2 # 2列目を書き換える
print(df)
```

**実行結果**

```
                    0    1
0  2022/01/01 0:30:00  500
1  2022/01/01 1:00:00  400
```